# Why can't I match ] with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I'm trying to match either `[` or `]` in a character set in sed but for some reason it doesn't like `]`

```
$ echo 'foo [bar]' | sed -E 's/[\[\]]//g'
foo [bar]
```

The following works:

```
$ echo 'foo [bar]' | sed -E 's/\]//g'
foo [bar
$ echo 'foo [bar]' | sed -E 's/[\[]//g'
foo bar]
```

But for some reason a `]` inside of that character set breaks it:

```
$ echo 'foo [bar]' | sed -E 's/[\]]//g'
foo [bar]
```

Oddly even this works:

```
$ echo 'foo [bar]' | sed -E 's/[]]//g'
foo [bar
$ echo 'foo [bar]' | sed -E 's/[[]//g'
foo bar]
```

But not this:

```
$ echo 'foo [bar]' | sed -E 's/[[]]//g'
foo [bar]
```

Do I just need some sort of extra escaping or is this even possible?

Comment: Not that it matters, but I'm noticing that you use `-E`, even though you use no extended regular expression. Would you want to delete the `[` and `]` characters from the string, use `tr -d '[]'` instead for simplicity.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Yeah I'm actually doing something way more sinister.  I have an array of patterns that I'm looping through to remove, some use extended regex and some don't.  So I'm just doing something like `for p in "${patterns[@]}"; do sed -E 's/'"$p"'//g' thing; done`

Comment: Huh. Ok. It would be slightly safer with `awk` though as it would not involve using the patterns as code, and `awk` already does extended regular expressions by default.

Comment: @jesse_b maybe `sed -E 's/'"$(printf '%s|' "${patterns[@]}" | sed s'/|$//')"'//g'` would be faster/more efficient.

Comment: @terdon: here I am living in 2022 while you are in 3022

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `]` or `[` do not need to be escaped within the bracket expression. Although backslash within bracket expression loses its escaping meaning and it matches literal backslash character. So when you do `[\]]`, you tell `sed` to match two characters: the `\` by the first `[\]` part immediately followed by `]`; but there is no matching for the `\]` string in your input, so no changes happening. To match a `]` character you only need `[]]` if you prefer to use it within bracket expression else literal `]` can be used too.

Also, note that within bracket expression `[...]`, character `]` must be the first character, so for this `'s/[[]]//g'` you should do `'s/[][]//g'`.